# Java relation between List and ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

why `1` is `ok` but `2` is `compilation error` and for `3` we get `warning message` (`List` is a raw type. References to generic type `List<E>` should be parameterized) and `4` gives again `compilation error`?

```
1- List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()//Ok
2- List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>()//compilation error
3- List<List> list = new ArrayList<List>()//Warning
4- List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>()//Compilation error
```

Comment: 2,4) You cant instantiate interfaces. 3) <List> also would like to know what type should it store.

Comment: @Pshemo very correct, the "List" also forces to implement all the abstract methods.

Answer (score 4):

`List` is an `interface`.

`ArrayList` is a class that `implements` `List`.

Think of `List` as being just a contract that can have multiple implementations (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`)

Answer (score 2):

1. `ArrayList` is class, that can be instantiate. So, no problem in 1.
2. `List` is interface. You can't instantiate interface. So, compilation error in 2 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are very new to Java. The reason is List is an interface. If you see definition of an interface, you can not instantiate it. ArrayList is an implementation of List interface which you can instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 - List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()//Ok
```

Because `ArrayList` implements `List` so `ArrayList` [**is a**](http://www.javacamp.org/moreclasses/oop/oop4.html) `List` and it can be pointed by reference variable of type `List`

```
2- List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>()//compilation error
```

You cant create object of `List` as its a [**interface**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/List.java) and not a class.

```
3- List<List> list = new ArrayList<List>()//Warning
```

Because inner `List` dont know what type of object it will store, it should be something like

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>()
```

to remove warning

```
4- List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>()//Compilation error
```

You can't create object of `List` as its a [**interface**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/List.java) and not a class.

Answer (score 0):

`List` is interface in `java.util.collection` package.
You can't instantiate interfaces.

ArrayList is concrete implementation of List interface.

```
ArrayList implements List
```

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented programming, we have the ability to write things that don't actually exist on their own. List is one of those things, it's an interface. An interface isn't actually doing anything with code, but rather it acts as a promise, or a contract.

There's a lot of different ways to create a list - some are slower in certain applications, some are faster. The two most popular are ArrayList and LinkedList. ArrayList backs your list in an array, supporting very fast indexing - you can get the object in position n very quickly. LinkedLists are faster at adding new objects and taking them away (not actually true, the reasons are a bit deeper than that). In some cases, one might be better, in other ones, the other might be.

So if I create a method that goes through a list and gets the data in each item, I'm not relying on the special features of either of those List implementations. Which one should I choose? Should I force the user to create an ArrayList from his LinkedList just because I arbitrarily decided that's the one that I would use?

List is the answer here. I'm not making any assumptions about how they created the list, all I'm doing is relying on some methods I know will be in every single list, so I don't make the user conform to me. But List by itself doesn't have anything to instantiate - when you call new List(), what does it mean? Well, it doesn't mean anything.

But, you can do

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>()
```

Why is that? The 'new' is being called on my actual implementation of the List, ArrayList. This isn't the common usage of it, but it is allowed, because there's actually a real list behind there - not just a promise of a list.